# issue automatically adding members to google groups (G-suite) with Admin SDK

Tags: google-admin-sdk

(I have done a search through the questions to see if I could find something on this, but have not found answers.)
I have two google groups through my G-suite and I want to automatically add people to both groups after they sign up for my club through a process on my website. I think this should be possible using:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members
I have gone into the API Console, created a new project, enabled the Admin SDKI API, and got an API key. However, I think I am running into the Authorization issue because we keep getting an error that the authorization token is missing.
I have tried using the OAuth 2.0 but I'm not sure if this should be "Internal" or "External". I'm not creating a whole app for someone to use - all I want to do is on the back end of the site take information that comes through when someone joins the club and automatically have them added to my google groups.
Is it possible for someone to please explain to me what I need to do?
I'm sorry this is kind of a basic question.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you checked the quickstarts documentation based on your preferred programming language? It contains the pre-requisite steps on how to enable your API and [create credentials](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials)

Comment: Thanks--I will check this out and double-check with my programmer.

Comment: Ok, we've continued to try to do this. We are using PHP, and we have looked at the relevant pages to create credentials. However, it seems that google doesn't want to accept the API key by itself. It looks like you need to have a live person authorize the access? I just want to have the system automatically take an email that someone has provided on my website because they have purchased a membership, and automatically add them to my google group. Does anyone else have any insights? I'd really appreciate it!